# Bash script says: "}" unexpected (expected "done") in function call in .xinitrc

Tags: bash

I'm writing the .xinitrc for my system, but the code (below) crashes on line 17 (the ending brace of the `freespace' function) with the error

> "}" unexpected (expected "done")

Is there actually a problem with the function declaration, or did I mess up somewhere else in the script?

```
while true; do
    # WiFi connectivity status
    if [ -f /sbin/iwgetid ]; then
        result="$(/sbin/iwgetid -r )";
        if [ -z "$result" ]; then
            result="Not connected";
        fi
    else
        result="Not installed";
    fi
    wifi_status="WiFi: $result";

    # Free space on / and /home
    function freespace {
        local space="$(df -lh --output=avail $1 | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//') free on $1";
        echo "$space";
    }

    root_free=$(freespace /);
    home_free=$(freespace /home);

    # Miscellaneous
    user_str="$(whoami)@$(hostname)";
    date_str="$(date +"%a %b %d %R")";

    # Battery status and CPU temperature
    if [ -f /usr/bin/acpi ]; then
        battery_status="Battery: $(acpi -b '{split($0, a, ": "); print a[2]'})";
        cpu_temp="CPU temperature: $(acpi -t -f | sed 's/Thermal 0: ok, //g')";
        acpi_status="$battery_status | $cpu_temp";
    else
        acpi_status="ACPI not available";
    fi

    # System performance
    uptime_str=$(uptime -p);
    num_cpus="CPUs: $(grep "processor" /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)";
    num_procs="$(ps -e | wc -l) active processes";
    load_avgs="Load averages: $(cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{split($0, a, " "); print a[1], a[2], a[3]}')";

    # Update top and bottom status bar
    top_bar="$wifi_status | $uptime_str | $user_str | $date_str";
    bottom_bar="$acpi_status | $num_cpus | $num_procs | $load_avgs | $root_free | $home_free";
    xsetroot -name "$top_bar;$bottom_bar";
    sleep 30;
done &

xbindkeys
( ( sleep 5 && /usr/bin/xscreensaver -no-splash -display :0.0 ) & )
( ( create-random-gradient && feh --bg-center ~/.wallpaper.png ) & )
( redshifter & )
wmname LG3D

exec /home/ma/build/dwm/dwm
```

If I slim down the code to just that section, i.e.

```
while true; do
    # Free space on / and /home
    function freespace {
        local space="$(df -lh --output=avail $1 | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//') free on $1";
        echo "$space";
    }
    root_free=$(freespace /);
    home_free=$(freespace /home);
    echo "$root_free | $home_free";
    sleep 2
done
```

and run it from the terminal directly (instead of calling `startx` after logging in), it works just fine.

Comment: You'll have fewer headaches if you use POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax. That is, `freespace() { ...; }`, with no preceding `function`.

Comment: And with respect to verifying syntax -- http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: Anyhow, if this code gets run with `sh` rather than `bash`, the noncompliant function declaration syntax will definitely be a problem.

Comment: BTW, re: "slim[ming] down the code" -- a proper [mcve] would be the shortest code *tested to produce the same problem*. Did you do that test with the segment? If so, it can/should be all that's included in the question -- there's no more need for the larger context at all at that point. (There's also surely more that can be removed while still producing the same error).

Comment: Defining a function inside a loop isn't necessarily *wrong*, but it's strange, unnecessary, and inefficient (since it gets redefined over & over again in exactly the same way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error will happen *if the shell running this code is not actually bash*. It's noteworthy that your script doesn't include a shebang -- without `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or another shebang, the interpreter used is unspecified. (Explicitly specifying `sh yourscript` will override the shebang and force `sh`, just as `bash yourscript` will ignore the shebang and use bash, but that's neither here nor there).

`function` is not a keyword in standard POSIX sh -- it's a ksh extension which bash adopted. Consequently, to a POSIX shell, the `{` in `function freespace {` is not syntax -- it's an *argument* to be passed to a command named `function`.

By contrast, the `}` *is* parsed as syntax, but it doesn't match with any syntactic opening brace; hence, your error.

In standards-compliant syntax, the declaration would be:

```
freespace() {
  df -lh --output=avail "$1" | awk -v fs="$1" 'NR == 2 { print $1 " free on " fs }'
}
```

Note the elimination of the unnecessary command substitution. `echo "$(...)"` is self-defeating: `$()` goes to significant overhead to capture stdout of its command into a string, and then `echo` emits that back to stdout again. Why do any of that when you could just run the command directly?

Comment: @MichaelA, ...btw, note that I've edited this to use `awk` to do work that was previously performed by `echo`.